# Error AutoFilter in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, jboss6.x

The problem that I have is that when I try to add the auto filter I get another error, not if I can help, here I leave the code and thanks:

```
prueba.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf((new AreaReference(new CellReference(0, 0), new CellReference(tmp.datos.size() - 1, tmp.columna.size() - 1))).formatAsString()));
```

and this is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError:  org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.get3DReferencePtg(Lorg/apac he/poi/ss/util/AreaReference; Lorg/apache/poi/ss/formula/SheetIdentifier;) Lorg/apache/poi/ss/formula/ptg/Ptg;
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.createAreaRefParseNode(FormulaParser.jav a:614)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeable(FormulaParser.java:449)  
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeExpression(FormulaParser.java: 237)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:112 6)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1086)  
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1073) 
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1433)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveExpression(FormulaParser.java:1533)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpression(FormulaParser.java:1517)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparisonExpression(FormulaParser.java:1474)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.unionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1454  
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:1575)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:145)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFName.setRefersToFormula(XSSFName.java:195) 
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.setAutoFilter(XSSFSheet.java:3138)
```

Comment: Looks like you have duplicate POI jars on your classpath - did you try the advice in [this POI FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006)?

Comment: Yes, I verified that it didn't have duplicated PDI and aparently everything is OK. When I verify POI FAQ and run the command. It gives me the route of ClassLoader of my POI library... Result:

Core POI came from file:/C:/Users/equipo/Documents/NetBeansProjects/trunk/lib/poi-3.11/poi-3.11-20141221.jar!/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.class

help.

Comment: Can you also check for an xssf class as well? There is a snippet for those in [the FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) as well. (As of 2 mins ago...)

Comment: I verified with the code you gave me and it also gives me the corrected results and without duplicates. Result:

    POI OOXML came from file:/C:/Users/auxsistemas2/Documents/NetBeansProjects/trunk/lib/poi-3.11/poi-ooxml-3.9.jar!/org/apache/poi/POIXMLDocument.class
    POI Scratchpad came from file:/C:/Users/auxsistemas2/Documents/NetBeansProjects/trunk/lib/poi-3.11/poi-scratchpad-3.11-20141221.jar!/org/apache/poi/hslf/HSLFSlideShow.class

Comment: I think I've spotted your problem - you have `poi-oo‌​xml-3.9.jar` in there. Swap that for the 3.11 ooxml jar and you should be fine

Comment: I was using version OOXML 3.11, but for different reasons with other components that I use in my project I had to get a lower version. I'm going to try again and let you know

Comment: After some tests, It gives me the following error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory.
newFactory()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory;.                            That's why I had to get a lower OOXML version

Comment: Try a nightly build, and/or a newer JVM

Comment: And if you want to use an older POI version, *all* your jars must be the same version

Answer (score 1):

You have three problems here. Firstly, as explained in [this Apache POI FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1019C)

> **Can I mix POI jars from different versions?**
>
> No. This is not supported.
>
> All POI jars in use must come from the same version. A combination such as poi-3.11.jar and poi-ooxml-3.9.jar is not supported, and will fail to work in unpredictable ways.

So, as you've said you've got a mix of 3.9 and 3.11 jars, that's your problem, that isn't supported. All your jars need to be the same version

Secondly, as discussed in the comments, if you can't work out what POI jars you are using, you need to follow [the directions in this POI FAQ Entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) which *exactly* describes your case, which has handy code to help you find what jars you are really using, which may not be the ones you *meant* to use!

Finally, there's a [POI FAQ on java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory.newFactory()]](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1017E) which explains that too. I'd suggest a newer, less broken JVM, but a newer POI (nightly, or 3.12 beta 2) should have a workaround in

Basically though, the [Apache POI FAQ page](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html) has you completely covered...